# OPENJSON running once per row of an INNER JOIN unnecessarily?

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, azure-sql-database

I have a table `MP_User` with 147 entries, and in order to query it, I am passing in JSON containing an array of "query objects", each of which has a unique ID and either an email address or a mobile number to match to user(s).  These get converted to one row each and matches with the users able through a `JOIN` operation.  User results need to be returned along with the unique ID.  Although the following query does work for this:

```
WITH QryCte AS (
    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON('[{"UniqueId":"0xy-5244249247924974924C","MobileNo":null,"Email":"joe.bloggs@domain.co.uk"},{...},...]') WITH (UniqueId nvarchar(max), MobileNo nvarchar(255), Email nvarchar(255))
)
SELECT
    usr.[user_id],
    usr.[firstname],
    usr.[surname],
    qry.[UniqueId] AS [temp_user_match_unique_id]
FROM
    [dbo].[mp_user] usr
    INNER JOIN QryCte qry ON (qry.[MobileNo] IS NOT NULL AND usr.[mobile_no] = qry.[MobileNo]) OR (qry.[Email] IS NOT NULL AND usr.[email] = qry.[Email])
```

... it seems to run very inefficiently on our Azure SQL database, taking 5-10 seconds to run (it's much quicker on my local SQL Server DB, but that's probably because of increased resources as the execution plan is the same).  The execution plan reveals:

[image: query execution plan]

... that the `OPENJSON` has been run 147 times, once for each row of the `MP_User` table, presumably because of the `INNER JOIN`.  However, I don't understand why SQL Server does this.  The result of `OPENJSON` isn't going to change and you'd think that making it the table in a CTE would give SQL Server the hint that it just needs to execute it once and cache the result table that can then be joined to in the CTE's `SELECT` statement.

How can I make SQL Server just run the `OPENJSON` once, put the result into a memory table, and join to that?  Is it possible to do in a CTE or do I need to use procedural code where I explicitly define the table variable and assign it?  I'd rather avoid that if possible as the CTE form looks more elegant I think.

Comment: Use a temp table & insert the parsed JSON to that instead of using the CTE
Then rewrrite the query to join to the temp table

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to solve this by creating a table variable to hold the results of `OPENJSON` and joining on that variable.  This forces SQL Server to actually create a temp table containing the query data rather than repeatedly running `OPENJSON`.  Apparently a CTE doesn't do that, even though I thought it did.  Presumably this applies to any table-valued function, actually.

This works, and results in `OPENJSON` only being run once (when deriving the data to fill the table variable with):

```
DECLARE @jsonQueryText nvarchar(max) = '[{"UniqueId":"0xy-5244249247924974924C","MobileNo":null,"Email":"joe.bloggs@domain.co.uk"},{...},...]';
DECLARE @Qry TABLE(UniqueId nvarchar(max), MobileNo nvarchar(255), Email nvarchar(255));
INSERT INTO @Qry SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@jsonQueryText) WITH (UniqueId nvarchar(max), MobileNo nvarchar(255), Email nvarchar(255));

SELECT
    usr.[user_id],
    usr.[firstname],
    usr.[surname],
    qry.[UniqueId] AS [temp_user_match_unique_id]
FROM
    [dbo].[mp_user] usr
    INNER JOIN @Qry qry ON (qry.[MobileNo] IS NOT NULL AND usr.[mobile_no] = qry.[MobileNo]) OR (qry.[Email] IS NOT NULL AND usr.[email] = qry.[Email])
```